# How to generate a list of unique years between several dates in Lumen/Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen, php-carbon

i'm creating an **API** in Lumen and i need to create a method that will get **dates from two colums** *on the same table* and return **any years that occur between those dates**, returning them all as a single array.

So for instance, imagine a table column named `start_date` and another named `end_date`

```
start_date | end_date          getAllYears() should return =>
                               [1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987,
                               1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                               ..., 2016]
1999-05-09 | 2002-04-03
1983-03-12 | 1987-09-23
2001-02-12 | 2016-11-27
```

Currently i have a method that manages to do this on other types of more specific queries, the major problem with this attempt, is that due to the sheer mass of SQL records that i'm retrieving, a method like this causes my request to time out every single time.

MY INEFFICIENT METHOD *that makes little use of Lumen/Laravel*

```
public function getAllYears(){
    $dates = $this->model->select('data_ini', 'data_fim')->get();

    $results = [];

    foreach ($dates as $obj){
        $carbonBegin = Carbon::createFromDate($obj->data_ini->year);
        $carbonEnd   = Carbon::createFromDate($obj->data_fim->year);

        if($carbonEnd->year === 9999){
            $carbonEnd->year = date('Y');
        }

        $carbonEnd->year++;
        // Simple method that runs a DatePeriod method
        $dateRange = $this->helper->createDateRange($carbonBegin, $carbonEnd);

        $results = array_merge($results, $dateRange);
    }
    sort($results);
    $cleanYears = array_unique($results);

    if ($cleanYears == null)
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'errorCode' => '1008', 'message' => "No years found!"]);
    else
        return response()->json(['error' => false, 'years' => $cleanYears]);
}
```

So, the question is, how can i do this in a less expensive way so that my server doesn't time out on every request? Thank in advance for your help :)

**NOTE: DB:raw is a no-go as my TL has forbidden me from using it anywhere on the API**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses):

```
$between = DB::table('theTable')->whereBetween('data_ini', ["str_to_date('2011-05-06','%Y-%m-%d')", "str_to_date('2011-05-06','%Y-%m-%d')"])->get();
```

**With models:**

```
$between = $this->model->whereBetween('data_ini', ["str_to_date('2011-05-06','%Y-%m-%d')", "str_to_date('2011-05-06','%Y-%m-%d')"])->get();
```

In the above, I am utilizing MySQL's built-in [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're not wrong, but you need raw queries to use mysql functions.

Comment: Great, that looks like it could work, i just need to parse min and max years beforehand and pass them in, however, i have another problem, in my `data_fim` column some of the dates have the year '9999' this is supposed to be converted to the current year, any easy way to do that with Query Builder?